# Is there a way to see the total number of entries in a channel in the CP?

Tags: entries, control-panel

Is there a plugin or something I'm missing in the CP to just see how many entries are under any given channel or structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the **Content Stats** plugin by Will Browar:

> https://github.com/wbrowar/contentstats

Comment: I love this CMS so much.